# Are there undecidable languages which are well defined?

Tags: undecidability

It would be a mess if the answer had to be NO after all these speculations and theorems about these languages but..

I am not conviced liar paradox is well defined. And Godël himself said his theorem is just an exhibit of a liar paradox.

I am not conviced halting problem is well defined.

I am pretty conviced that if you formalize the statement 'Does this man both having only 2 ears and 3 ears went to his house on monday ?' you get something that you can not prove true nor false, just because it would suppose to define something in the proof which can not be defined.

I am not conviced that any 'undecidable' Godel statement is undecidable in an other meaning than this.

I am pretty conviced than you can not correctly define any consistent theory that would not be decidable by a turing machine. I think this is the profond meaning of Church Thesis.

I am pretty conviced that if you take a statement which would be undecidable even for a turing machine, if you add this statement as axiom to any turing complete theory, you get something inconsistent because I am pretty conviced than you can proof both the statement and it's unprovability.

I am not sure that the separation of syntax and semantic is relevant anywhere in theoretical computer science, yes you can specify what you are doing and it can help in some application, but I am pretty conviced you do not need this do define mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem really is well-defined. Allow me to state it in terms of languages as you'd want.

Recall the definition of a decidable language. A language $L$ is decidable iff there exists a Turing machine $T$ such that for all inputs it can decide whether the input word is part of the language in a finite number of steps.

Furthermore, let us remind ourselves that Turing machines are universal, and can simulate each other. That is we can build a Turing machine $U$ that given some encoding of another Turing machine $T$ and input $x$ when run $U$ will have the same outcome (yes/no/does not halt) as $T$ would on $X$. They are also countable, so for each Turing machine there is an encoding and vice versa.

Now let $L$ be the language of the encodings of Turing machines that halt when they receive their own encoding as input. Assume there exists a Turing machine $D$ that correctly decides this language. Construct $H$ to run $D$ on its input (similar to $U$), but unlike $U$ if $D$ returns yes it goes into an infinite loop and otherwise halts with some value.

Now asking if $H \in L$ gives us a contradiction, so our assumptions are wrong . But we got $H$ from $D$ in simple finite computable steps. Thus it must be our assumption that $D$ exists is wrong. But if that assumption does not hold we must conclude that $L$ is not decidable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a repackaging of the halting problem you may find easier to think about:

Consider the **Diophantine solution problem**: which Diophantine equations (= polynomials with integer coefficients set equal to zero) have solutions? This is about as concrete as things get, yet by the [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) this is basically the halting problem in disguise. Specifically, there is a computable function $f$ from (indices for) Turing machines to (codes for) Diophantine equations such that $f(e)$ has a zero iff $e$ halts on input $0$, and so a fortiori there is no algorithm for determining whether a given Diophantine equation has a solution.

And many more examples of concrete non-logic-based conditions yielding non-computable sets can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11540/what-are-the-most-attractive-turing-undecidable-problems-in-mathematics). In particular, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/103415/8133) specifies a *single Diophantine equation* whose instances with respect to one variable (e.g. take a particular variable and think about plugging in specific natural numbers for it) yield non-computability.

---

I suspect your confusions stem from taking a "quick summary" too seriously. E.g. when you write

> Godël himself said his theorem is just an exhibit of a liar paradox,

you're treating a vague intuition as a rigorous result, and it's really not. The incompleteness theorem is *motivated by* the Liar Paradox, but that doesn't mean that it *is* the Liar Paradox, and this will become clear if you examine in detail a proof of the theorem. (I **strongly** recommend a modern presentation, rather than Godel's original argument, since the details have been substantially cleared up over the last several decades; in math you usually *don't* want to go back to the original source.)